# MYSQL database connectivity using php error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to connect to MySql database but it gives an error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\register.php on line 4
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\register.php on line 4

```
<?php       
session_start();        
$db = mysqli_connect('loacalhost', 'root', 'system', 'authentication');        
if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
    session_start();    

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);     
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);    
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);     
    $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password2']);        

    if ($password == $password2) {     //create user   
        $password = md5($password); //hash for security purpose  
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) 
            VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
   
        mysqli_query($db,$sql);     
        $_SESSION['message' ] = "U R LOGGED IN";
        $_SESSION['usrname'] = $username;   
        header("location: home.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message' ] = "the two passwords do not match";
               
    }   
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>    
        <title>Register , login and logout user php mysql </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Register , login and logout user php mysql</h1>
        </div>
        
        <form method="post" action="register.php>     
            <table>     
                <tr>    
                    <td> username: </td>    
                    <td> <input type="text" name="username" class="textInput"></td>   
                </tr>   
                <tr>    
                    <td>Email:</td>     
                    <td><input type="email" name="email" class="textInput"></td>     
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td>password:</td>  
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" class="textInput"></td>   
                </tr>   
                <tr>    
                    <td>password again:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password2" class="textInput"></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>    
                    <td>username:</td>  
                    <td><input type="submit" name="register_btn" value="Register"></td>    
                </tr>   
            </table>
        </form>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds like a name resolution failure.  Add more details about your server environment.  Your connection string.  etc.

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - We can't help you unless you show us the code. We're not mind readers.

Comment: `loacalhost` !== `localhost`

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's _very_ insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Your `action="register.php>` is missing the closing `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the line

```
$db = mysqli_connect('loacalhost', 'root', 'system', 'authentication');
```

The `localhost` is written as `loacalhost`.

So the actual code should be

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'system', 'authentication');
```

This will solve the error

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\register.php on line 4
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\register.php on line 4

Answer (score -1):

Probably your mysqli_connect syntax is wrong.

The right syntax is for example :

```
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: ...or the OP has simply written an invalid hostname. We should wait to write an answer until the OP has given us more info. Right now, we're just stabbing in the dark.